# Cannot install \usepackage{url}

Tags: installing, miktex

Can you just guide me out with how to install package from the MiKTeX Package Manager. I cannot install it.

Comment: Nothing mysterious: You just have to launch the package manager. A list of all available packages, in alphabetical order, will appear after a few seconds. To speed up things you can use the tool bar and enter  `url` in the `Name:`edit box, then click on `Filter`. A list of the packages that contain url in their names appears. Right click on `url`and ask to install. That's all.

Comment: Relevant: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are on Windows. If so, it is possible to install it as admin. Follow the instructions of  @Bernard and then click on the + icon in the tool bar to proceed.